# Como extraer los datos de react bootstrap table2

Tags: reactjs

Ayuda necesito enviar los datos que tiene formatter row al momento que presione actualizar este abre un modal y intento que la información que contiene row aparezca en el modal, pero al presionar el boton actualizar no captura nada

````
 const TableRol = ({handleShow,datos})=> {

    const columns = [{
        dataField: 'Usuario',
        text: 'Usuario'
    }, {
        dataField: 'Rol',
        text: 'Rol'
    }, 
    {
        dataField: 'id',
        text: 'Acciones',
        formatter: (cell, row, rowIndex, extraData) => (

            <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title="Opciones">
                <Dropdown.Item onSubmit={row} onClick={handleShow} >Actualizar</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Visualizar</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
            </DropdownButton>
        )
    }
    ]

    return <BootstrapTable keyField='id' data={ datos } columns={ columns } />
}
export default {TableRol};```
````

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolver esto enviando row en la función handleShow(row) que utiliza mi modal

```
        dataField: 'id',
        text: 'Acciones',
        formatter: (cell, row, rowIndex, extraData) => (

            <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title="Opciones">
                <Dropdown.Item onClick={handleShow(row)} >Actualizar</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Visualizar</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
            </DropdownButton>
```